# react view with node backend routing

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

i am going to start to build a web application i am confused with

1. react routing and node routing how can handle this?
2. how to configure both that run on one port
3. how could I use authentication to manage session and send from node to react for checking the session created or not.

I tried with this: https://github.com/prakashpandey0/reactexpress.git

According to provided link i have done the basic things.

Comment: There are many existing resources for all parts of this; do more research

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReactJS and ExpressJS are a good framework to build a web application. A couple of things for your requirements.

1. a)  React Routing (`react-router-dom`) is used for navigating and redirecting to different pages/components in the front-end application - Refer [this blog](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf) for a good start.

   b) Node Routing is used to create API endpoints using `express.router()` - Refer [this blog](https://medium.com/@jeffandersen/building-a-node-js-rest-api-with-express-46b0901f29b6)
2. Developing the front-end and the server-side on the same port will be complex and it's always a good practice of developing front-end and server-side in separate ports
3. For authentication, `express-session` can be used where we can assign the userID in the session when user logs in and for each API call, we can check whether the user is logged or not using the userID in the sessions. [Refer this blog](https://medium.com/@evangow/server-authentication-basics-express-sessions-passport-and-curl-359b7456003d)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for suggestions :) . but one thing more could i able to pass session on react view to show headers navs like profile and logout if they are login . because i am not able to check session on react view or make session component or something else(which i don't know right now) that will check always is there is session created or not ?

Comment: @PrakashPandey For the react view, you can pass a jwt token in your response from the node server

Comment: ok that token could be store in localStorage or sessionStorage because i prefer sessionStorage but is it good way to do ?